# Parsing MJPEG stream with C# net7.0 on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, mjpeg, .net-7.0, net-7.0-ios

I want to parse a MJPEG stream with net7.0 on iOS. My current solution is working on windows and android, but on iOS I can not receive the raw stream.

What is MJPEG? MJPEG is a constant stream of jpegs. The content starts with header informations, after that is an image, and after that there is a header again in the content.
Example of a response:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 50706


{Image}

Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 50750


{Image2}
```

After the header, there are always 2 line breaks.
So I parse the response to find 2 line breaks, parse the `Content-Lenght` and know, that the following 50706 bytes are the image. I extract the image from the stream parse for the next 2 line breaks and so on.

My code is like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage headerResponse = await client.GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
Stream stream = headerResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
{Parsing stuff} ...
```

My problem now is, that iOS is not handing over the raw content.
There are no header informations in the content stream. It is like this:

```
{Image}
{Image2}
```

So there is no way for me to split the stream in single images.
The `headerResponse.Content.GetContentLegth()` is not the correct value, also it is not changing while parsing the stream.
I already tried different HttpClients ([NSUrlSessionHandler, CFNetworkHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack?source=recommendations))

So is there a way, to prevent iOS from removing the Header informations from the content stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is running now, thanks to 2 posts I found in the internet:
[Swift Mjpeg Streaming Only Showing Single Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617278/swift-mjpeg-streaming-only-showing-single-frame) and [Download Files in Xamarin iOS in the Background](https://doumer.me/download-files-in-xamarin-ios-in-the-background/)

My solution is a mix of both

```
public class MyImageReceiver
{
    public async Task Get(string requestUri, Action<IEnumerable<byte>> imageReceived, int timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool isTimeout = false;
        DateTime lastImageReceivedAt = DateTime.Now;

        var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
        using (NSUrl nsUrl = NSUrl.FromString(requestUri))
        using (NSMutableUrlRequest request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(nsUrl,
                cachePolicy: NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
                timeoutInterval: 2000))
        using (CameraPictureClientSessionDelegate cameraPictureClientSessionDelegate = new CameraPictureClientSessionDelegate())
        using (NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, cameraPictureClientSessionDelegate, null))
        using (NSUrlSessionDataTask streamingTask = session.CreateDataTask(request: request))
        {
            request.HttpMethod = "GET";


            cameraPictureClientSessionDelegate.ImageReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                lastImageReceivedAt = DateTime.Now;
                _waitHandle.Release();
                imageReceived(e);
            };
            
            streamingTask.Resume();

            do
            {
                await _waitHandle.WaitAsync(timeout, cancellationToken);
                if ((DateTime.Now - lastImageReceivedAt).TotalMilliseconds > timeout)
                {
                    isTimeout = true;
                }
            }
            while ((streamingTask.State == NSUrlSessionTaskState.Running
                    || streamingTask.State == NSUrlSessionTaskState.Suspended)
                    && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested
                    && !isTimeout);
            if (streamingTask.State == NSUrlSessionTaskState.Running
                || streamingTask.State == NSUrlSessionTaskState.Suspended)
            {
                streamingTask.Cancel();
            }
            if (isTimeout)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the delegate

```
public class CameraPictureClientSessionDelegate :
    NSUrlSessionDataDelegate,
    INSUrlSessionTaskDelegate
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    public event EventHandler<IEnumerable<byte>> ImageReceived;
    List<byte> _data = new List<byte>();
    public override void DidReceiveData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSData data)
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore.Wait();
            _data.AddRange(data.ToArray());
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public override void DidReceiveResponse(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSUrlResponse response, Action<NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition> completionHandler)
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore.Wait();
            if (_data.Count > 0)
            {
                ImageReceived?.Invoke(this, _data);
                _data = new List<byte>();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Allow);
    }
}
```